# c# - The 'ClientID' option must be provided - Azure API - Connect to AzureSQL using managed identity

Tags: c#, azure, connection, identity, managed

I have built an API as an Azure Web app that will be hosted through Azure API Management Service. I need the app to connect to an AzureSQL database using a system assigned managed identity.

```
var credential = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential(); // system-assigned identity
  
// Get token for Azure SQL Database
var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));

// Add the token to the SQL connection
var conn = new SqlConnection(_connStringRules);
conn.AccessToken = token.Token;

conn.Open();
```

Connection string:
Server=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Managed Identity";

But I am getting the error The 'ClientID' option must be provided
I am using dapper instead of EF, and following the below tutorial (coding aspect)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet

I am using a system assigned identity, with the Contributor role assigned to it
[image: identity]
[image]

So I am not sure why I am being asked for a clientid?

Does this refer to client id you get when adding an identity provider?
[image]

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?  Any ideas welcome!!!

Comment: How are you getting the token? Are you getting it from "DefaultAzureCredentia()"?

Comment: @AjayManagaon - yes - just adjusted the code snippet to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect Azure sql server from Azure web API with system assigned managed identity authentication give connection string in below format in Appsetting.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "QuotesDatabase": "Server=tcp:<servename>.database.windows.net,1433; Database=<databasename>;" }
```

Use below code for connection.

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("<connectionstringname>");
                services.AddTransient(a =>{
                    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                    var token = credential
                            .GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                                new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
                    sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
                    return sqlConnection;
```

[image]

I set admin as you want to the sql server.

[image]

choose administrator account for azure service authentication to retrieve the token credentials.

Image for reference:

[image]

Enable system assigned manage identity in on state of Azure app service.

[image]

Login to sql server with administrator add user to the database and assign role to the user

```
create user [<appName>] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [<appName>];
alter role db_datawriter add member [<appName>];
```

[image]

The database successfully connected to the app.

Image for reference:

[image]